# mixed tenses: present perfect + future will

Tags: tenses

Can we use present perfect and future tenses in one sentence to talk about a project that had started in the past and is predicted to be completed in a particular year?

e.g.

> The implementation of one power substation has begun and will be completed in 2019.

Comment: We commonly get questions such as yours on this site, asking whether it is permissible to mix tenses in a sentence. I would be interested to know if a teacher or grammar book has led you to believe that mixing tenses results in ungrammatical sentences.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! I might also recommend visiting [the English Language Learners Stack Exchange](https://ell.stackexchange.com). They can be a most valuable resource.

Answer (score 3):

On closer observation you may notice that your sentence consists of two clauses, namely

> The implementation of one power station has begun.

and

> [It] will be completed in 2019.

the "it" being "the implementation of one power station".

This is an entirely valid structure and combining the two clauses to a single sentence is an entirely valid choice.